# "Could not verify application public id from IQ Server" in nexusPolicyEvaluation step jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, nexus, nexus-iq

in my jenkins file in the step that runs the following command

```
nexusPolicyEvaluation failBuildOnNetworkError: true, iqApplication: "${APPLICATION_NAME}", iqScanPatterns: [[scanPattern: '**/build/libs/*.jar']], iqStage: 'build'
```

results in the following error

```
com.sonatype.insight.client.utils.NiceHttpResponseException: Authentication failed due to LDAP error. Please contact your IT administrator. (ID ea20d0c059df4f62)
    at com.sonatype.insight.client.utils.AbstractClient.verifyStatusCode(AbstractClient.java:29)
    at com.sonatype.insight.brain.client.AbstractRequestClient.parseResult(AbstractRequestClient.java:23)
    at com.sonatype.insight.brain.client.ConfigurationClient.verifyOrCreateApplication(ConfigurationClient.java:111)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.iq.impl.DefaultIqClient.verifyOrCreateApplication(DefaultIqClient.java:96)
Caused: com.sonatype.nexus.api.exception.IqClientException: Could not verify application public id from IQ Server
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.iq.impl.DefaultIqClient.verifyOrCreateApplication(DefaultIqClient.java:99)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.api.iq.IqClient$verifyOrCreateApplication$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.iq.IqPolicyEvaluatorUtil.evaluatePolicy(IqPolicyEvaluatorUtil.groovy:75)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.iq.IqPolicyEvaluatorUtil$evaluatePolicy.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.iq.PolicyEvaluatorExecution.run(PolicyEvaluatorExecution.groovy:54)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.ci.iq.PolicyEvaluatorExecution.run(PolicyEvaluatorExecution.groovy)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The plugin installed in Jenkins is the following Nexus Platform Plugin
Version3.16.489.v7cf06846a_c96
the Nexusiq version is

At times it works well and the result is the following

```
The detailed report can be viewed online at https://nexusiq.com.ar/ui/links/application/concesionarias-bff/report/205ed7d276a84ecb9d6f818171d383ea
Summary of policy violations: 18 critical, 6 severe, 9 moderate
IQ Server evaluation of application concesionarias-bff detected warnings
```